# Determine GIF Animation Status?

Tags: javascript, animated-gif

Is there any way to detect via javascript whether a GIF image's animation is completed or not?

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Comment: @DanielA.White, Is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now it's possible. There are packages available to extract information from byte buffer. Like [`gif-info`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gif-info).

Combining that with [`HTMLImage.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) it's possible to start timeout exactly with delay when animation should already ended.

Or having duration value we can set up CSS animation on target image that would work in more stable way.

But although it's technically possible it still looks as overkill.

Comment: Yes, definitely an overkill but also very useful who needs it. :)

Comment: @Aniruddh probably it's way more easier to convert gif->video and get full control over playing

Comment: I think you are correct. Back then it was not possible to control videos.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not. Javascript cannot manipulate GIF directly. But maybe [jsgif](http://slbkbs.org/jsgif/) can help you

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about another way

Comment: You could possibly use a sprite map controlled by CSS animations instead. http://gif2sprite.com/  I'm intending to try this myself soon but have not yet,  let me know how you go.