# Make GIF disappear after getting played once with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, gif

This question has kinda been answered before however the answer doesn't really work for me since I need my GIF to actually disappear after getting played once since its a GIF of png image that fades away.

I have a function that replaces my image with my gif however the problem that I have is that it keeps on looping but I need it to disappear after getting played once.

```
function muda_cad () {
            cad1.src='images/cadeado/cadeado-gif.gif'
        }
```

Comment: Well JavaScript has no clue about gifs and looping.... You can write code to hide it after X amount of time.... Or make it so your gif does not repeat....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine GIF Animation Status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063800/determine-gif-animation-status)

Comment: actually packages like [`gif-info`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gif-info) should help. but it looks like real overkill. it'd be better to rethink the approach - say `<video />` matches your needs better and nowadays [it does not mean](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/replace-animated-gifs-with-video/) heavy traffic load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS doesn't know about git loop, but if you know the time, you can create a delay with [SetTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
function muda_cad () {
    cad1.src='images/cadeado/cadeado-gif.gif'
    // Wait 1sec and replace by png
    setTimeout(function() {
        cad1.src='images/cadeado/cadeado-png.png'
    }, 1000) 
}
```

Comment: idk how I didn't think of this, but yeah it worked for me so thank you

Comment: what if the gif is longer/shorter than 1 second?

Comment: im making the gif myself, but I can easily adjust the 1 second to my gif's length obviously